# Библиотеки для python для вставки javascript в pdf документ

Tags: javascript, python, pdf, library

Подскажите пожалуйста библиотеку для python, чтобы иметь возможность вставить JavaScript в существующий pdf документ.

Необходимо создавать с помощью python pdf-документы с шаблоном и встроенным javascript (open action), используя методы для JavaScript из документации JavaScript API для Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: [`PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter.addJS`](https://gist.github.com/rms1000watt/177970ce9fb0970e765700f12695231d) работает в вашем случае? ([javascript при открытии выполняется](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileWriter.html#PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter.addJS))

Comment: Если думаете что нашли решение, то опубликуйте как ответ — [это явно приветствуется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) (когда SO репутация 15ти достигнет)